# How to insert/retrieve json data form/to file.json using Mysql / spring

Tags: mysql, json

i'm making a quiz app which read questions from an external json file, i want to add the file to Mysql in case i want to add/ modify my questions, so right now my file look like this

```
{
"id": 1,
"name": "first Quiz",
"description": "blabla",
"questions": [
    {
        "id": 1010,
        "name": "my first question",
        "questionTypeId": 1,
        "options": [
            {
                "id": 1055,
                "questionId": 1010,
                "name": "answer 1",
                "isAnswer": false
            },
            {
                "id": 1056,
                "questionId": 1010,
                "name": "answer 2",
                "isAnswer": true
            },
            {
                "id": 1057,
                "questionId": 1010,
                "name": "answer 3",
                "isAnswer": false
            },
            {
                "id": 1058,
                "questionId": 1010,
                "name": "answer 4",
                "isAnswer": false
            }
        ],
        "questionType": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Multiple Choice",
            "isActive": true
        }
    },
```

and then the second question,

so i was able to save the json file in Mysql using https://sqlizer.io/ , but when i retreive it to save it from Mysql to file it changed it's structure, is there another method (a simple one ) to solve this , since saving the whole json as a string isn't an option (consider having 200 questions)
can anyone help me? im using angular 4 and spring boot

Answer (score 0):

I solved my prob by creating the json by myself with spring and save it in a file,
this tuto helped me a lot https://www.journaldev.com/2324/jackson-json-java-parser-api-example-tutorial
 , i'm still having a prob with Mysql when parsing my json but for now i'm gonna leave it like this and go back to check it later